# Merging an http request result with Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm sorry about my confusing title but I basically have an Interface

```
export interface Tutor {
  name: string;
  rating: number;
  personalInfo: string;
}
```

And a function that Is getting a list of so-called Tutors from my back-end:

```
public loadTutors() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/loadTutors';
    this.http.get<Tutor[]>(url).pipe(map(tutor =>
      tutor.forEach(tut => this.tutors.push(tut))))
      .subscribe();
    console.log(this.tutors);
  }
```

There are more fields in entity model of my back-end project then in Tutor Interface and adding a new Entity for only this specific request doesn't seem like a good scalable solution. 
After the function I get something like this:

```
Array(2)
0:
username: "Some Username"
email: null
name: null
password: "$2a$11$T44uetsjh1HxLu/ilsTiMODu.aoKLf8/zo3WPM/FUjeMXZRkpDz1S"
balance: 0
personalInfo: "Some personal Info"
rating: 0
userRoles: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
...
```

What would be the best practice of iterating through response fields or fitting the response to the Tutor Interface?

Thank you for your time and responses in advanced and I hope that you'll have a nice day!

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just pluck what I need.

I would do:

```
public loadTutors() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/loadTutors';
    this.http.get<Tutor[]>(url).pipe(
        // pluck name, rating, personalInfo from backend response and return it as an object
        map(tutors => tutors.map(({ name, rating, personalInfo })=> ({ name, rating, personalInfo }))),
      )
      .subscribe(tutors => {
        console.log(tutors);
        this.tutors = tutors;
        console.log(this.tutors);
      });
  }
```

The non ES6 way to write the map would be

```
map(tutor => ({ name: tutor.name, rating: tutor.rating, personalInfo: tutor.personalInfo })
```

Answer (score 1):

The interface is just a model, it doesn't mean it convert the variables into that model, you have to do it manually. Then it is better to use the map function instead of pushing into the array. I also recommend you to run the console.log inside the subscribe because the http get method is asynchronous.

```js
public loadTutors() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/loadTutors';
    this.http.get<Tutor[]>(url).pipe(
      map(tutors => {
         this.tutors = tutors.map(tut => {
           return {
             name: tut.name,
             rating: tut.rating,
             personalInfo: tut.personalInfo
           }
         })
      })
    ).subscribe(() => {
       console.log(this.tutors)
    })

}
```